# Even if app is installed, Deeplink go to install page

Tags: android-deep-link, phantom-wallet

When I use deeplink in mobile chrome broswer,

Even though there's a phantom app installed on my mobile,
Occasionally, it will be taken to the app installation page.

how to fix it?

- code

```js
function build_url(path: string, params: URLSearchParams) {
        return `https://phantom.app/ul/v1/${path}?${params.toString()}`;
    }


const params = new URLSearchParams({
            dapp_encryption_public_key,
            cluster: "devnet",
            app_url: "https://phantom.app",
            redirect_link, // redirect to my server
        });

const uri = build_url("signTransaction", params);
window.open(uri);
```

- screenshot

[image]

- Device info

```
Galaxy21 5G SM-G991N G991NKSS3CVI3 / G991NOKR3CVI3 / G991NKOU3CVH1

Android version : 12

Phantom App version : 22.09.06

Chrome version : 105.0.5195.136
```

Comment: If you use `phantom://<version>/<method>` what is the effect?
https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/deeplinks-ios-and-android

Comment: @bashford7
When using the connect method, the app turns on, but signing window does not appear.
sorry i forgot `version`. I'll try it again.

Comment: @bashford7
same as before